# Is there a way to see what query speeds by parse open source server

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I switched over to the parse open source server because `parse.com` is shutting down. My app all works except when I query objects it takes about three seconds to return a value. This is a issue because my app will have a lot of users and I can not have it go slowly every time some one uses it. I tried updating mLab but it did not make a difference. It is on AWS and I am using the IOS SDK. Is there a way to see what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue!